# 403 error forbidden you don't have permission to access /myapp on this server mod_wsgi and apache

Tags: mod-wsgi, raspbian, wsgi, http-status-code-403, apache2.4

I have installed mod_wsgi as an Apache module and I want to run a simple hello world application to see that the module works properly.
I have followed [this](https://www.shellhacks.com/modwsgi-hello-world-example/) guide, which is based on the official [Quick Configuration Guide](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html).
After completing all the steps I get a 403 error
`Forbidden You don't have permission to access /myapp on this server.`.
I am using Apache/2.4.10 on Raspbian and my installed mod_wsgi version is
`libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 4.3.0-1 armhf Python 3 WSGI adapter module for Apache.`

I have added example.com to my hosts' file as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost example.com
```

I created the example.com.conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` with contents:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com
ServerAdmin test@test.com

DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/documents
<Directory /usr/local/www/documents>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi
<Directory /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

myapp.wsgi contents:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
status = '200 OK'
output = 'Hello World!\n'
response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
start_response(status, response_headers)
return [output]
```

and created the files/folders for the hello world application with the following permissions:

```
drwxr-sr-x 2 root www-data 4096 Feb  1 13:18 documents
drwxr-sr-x 2 root www-data 4096 Feb  1 13:22 wsgi-scripts
```

I also made sure that example.com is served locally and not through DNS with ping.

I cannot understand why my installation is not working.

Are any further configuration options missing or is there something wrong with any of my settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a few modifications.
The new `example.com.conf` file is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com

DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/documents
<Directory /usr/local/www/documents>
Require all granted
Satisfy Any
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi
<Directory /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts>
<Files myapp.wsgi>
Require all granted
Satisfy Any
</Files>
</Directory>
```

After the syntax changed to match apache 2.4 I got 500 Internal Server Error, which upon further investigation inside apache `error.log` file indicated the following error:

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 11216] [client 127.0.0.1:56642] mod_wsgi (pid=11216): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi'.
[wsgi:error] [pid 11216] [client 127.0.0.1:56642] TypeError: sequence of byte string values expected, value of type str found
```

To solve this error I changed the `output` variable assignment in `myapp.wsgi` file from `output = 'Hello World!\n'`
to `output = b'Hello World!'` as it is indicated [here](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/tests/hello.wsgi).